# VM Ware Fusion 3 - Eliminate windows apps from Open With menu on Mac

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

How can I eliminate the Windows applications from my Open with menu in OS X.

Example...right click a .jpg file in OS X...Open with...Paint - XP shows up.

Any easy way to eliminate these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the virtual machine, then menu: Virtual Machine -> Settings -> Applications -> Default Applications -tab, "Open your Mac files and web links using ...", uncheck (also check the configure button).

Comment: Thanks - looks like I have to go through this process for each VM I have :-(